# Randomize dataset in a Wix repeater

Tags: dataset, repeater, velo

I'm building a website in Wix, and I'm trying to build something like Mental Floss's Fact Generator (https://www.mentalfloss.com/amazingfactgenerator) on my website.

I have a dataset ready to go, and have linked it to a repeater, but I've got some problems randomizing the information coming from the dataset, and getting the repeater to only display one entry from the database at a time, then a different entry on refresh.

The code I've used to randomize the database looks like this:

```
let items;
function shuffleArray() {
 let itemsLength = items.length, lastItem, randomIndex;
 while (itemsLength) {
      randomIndex = Math.floor(Math.random() * itemsLength--);
      lastItem = items[itemsLength];
      items[itemsLength] = items[randomIndex];
      items[randomIndex] = lastItem;
  }
 return items;
}
$w.onReady( () => {
  $w("#dataset1").onReady( () => {
    $w("#dataset1").getItems(0, 1000)
    .then( (results) => {
      items = results.items;
    $w("#repeater1").data = shuffleArray(items);
  })
  })
})
```

I have *no* coding knowledge, so I'm really fumbling around in the dark here, sorry.

Any help on randomizing the dataset, and getting it to display just one entry from the dataset at a time would be amazing.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

If you want to randomly show data in your repeater do not use a dataset. Query the database collection using the Wix Data API directly and inject the values into the repeater.

So basically when the page loads I will initiate a database query to get the items

```
import wixData from 'wix-data';

$w.onReady(function () {
    initiate();
});

function initiate() {
    wixData.query('myCollectionId')
    .limit(1000) //gets the maximum number of items allowed
    .find() //if you have database permissions then run this query on the backend
    .then( (results) => {
        let array = results.items;
        let random = shuffle(array); //shuffle data
        $w("#repeater1").data = random; //set repeater data
    });
}
```

Please remember to change the placeholder collection id above to your actual database collection'ID'. As you can see in the code above I receive the items from the database and call the shuffle function which randomizes your array as shown below.

```
function shuffle(array) {
    var currentIndex = array.length, temporaryValue, randomIndex;
    while (0 !== currentIndex) {
        randomIndex = Math.floor(Math.random() * currentIndex);
        currentIndex -= 1;
        temporaryValue = array[currentIndex];
        array[currentIndex] = array[randomIndex];
        array[randomIndex] = temporaryValue;
    }
    return array;
}
```

Once my array is shuffled I set the repeaters data to that of the shuffled array. I also need to setup the repeater to display values so we use onItemReady() for that as shown below.

```
export function repeater1_itemReady($item, itemData, index) {
    $item("#name").text = itemData.name;
    $item("#number").text = itemData.number;
    $item("#website").text = itemData.website;
}
```

In the code above I created the onItemReady function from the properties panel. You will need to change all the element ids to your own and adjust the code according to your own needs.

**Showing only 1 item:**

The above code will populate the repeater with all the items (shuffled) but since you want only 1 at a time we just pick the first item to display by making a small change inside the .then() statement of our wixData.query()

```
$w("#repeater1").data = [random[0]];
```